# How to close GUI and go into pure shell mode in RedHat enterprise Linux 6?

Tags: linux, shell

I'm new to linux. How to close GUI and go into pure shell mode in RedHat enterprise Linux 6? I don't want the GUI. I just want to learn some shell scripts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you boot your server in run level 3 or you use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> go to terminal mode :)

Runlevels Descriptions

- 0 – halt
- 1 – Single user mode
- 2 – Multiuser, without NFS (The same as 3, if you do not have networking)
- 3 – Full multiuser mode (terminal mode)
- 4 – unused
- 5 – X11 (X mode)
- 6 – reboot

To change the default runlevel in RedHat/CentOS/Fedora, edit `/etc/inittab` and find the line that looks like this:

```
id:5:initdefault:
```

change to 3, then reboot the server

Comment: +1 For listing all the options.

Comment: Alternately, you can just run, as root: "telinit 3" to temporarily change the run-level to 3 to try it out.  Then if it is not working out for you, you can do "telinit 5" or just reboot the system to get back to the GUI.

Comment: Good post. I'll add: CTRL+ALT+Backspace as a way of forcefully killing the GUI session (though it may restart afterwards). Also, you can usually cycle between a number of terminals with CTRL+ALT+F1-7. F7 typically returns you to the GUI, though this might vary with different distros. Try them out :)